# Variation of coupon collecting problem

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

I have a doubt in coupon collecting problem. I am not able to understand how to approach this problem.
"*Suppose you already have 10 different coupons when there are 20 coupon types. What is the expected number of boxes for obtaining a coupon different from the 10 you already have?*"

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** The probability of getting a box with a different coupon from the $10$ already gotten would be $\frac12$. The expected value for the number of trials to get a result that has probability $p$ is
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty kp(1-p)^{k-1}
&=p\frac1{(1-(1-p))^2}\\
&=\frac1p
\end{align}
$$

Comment: So if I am right in the next two boxes I will have a new coupon. Right!

Comment: On average, you will get a new coupon in the next two boxes. There is a $\frac34$ chance that a new coupon will be in the next two boxes.

Comment: So had there been 16 coupons already collected and total of 20 in the above question: then p=1/5 so 1/p =5.

Comment: So doesn't this mean that in the next 5 boxes I will get a coupon. Why do you say average and probability over this? Please give some hint.

Comment: There is no guarantee that in the next 5 boxes you will get a new coupon. In $20\%$ of the instances, you would get a new coupon in the next box. In $16\%$ of the instances, you would get a new coupon in the second box. In $12.8\%$, you would get a new coupon in the third box. In $10.24\%$, in the fourth box. In $8.192\%$, in the fifth box. That leaves $32.768\%$ that you won't get one until a later box. The average number of boxes needed to get the next new coupon will be $5$.